# jar bundle and its classpath in ServiceMix-karaf

Tags: osgi, bundle, classpath, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am developing 2 jar files (jar1 and jar2 - the packaging type in pom.xml of 2 jars is jar) and installed them into serviceMix. Jar1 will use some packakes from jar2.

In the manifest.mf files, i used import and export for jar1 and jar2. After installing into serviceMix 4.3.0. Everything going almost fine. From jar 1, i can use packages in jar2 (i know that by debugging the code). But the problem is here:

```
The structure of Jar2: 
  jar2:/ 
        . 
        com 
               abc 
                   .......(classes) 
        META-INF 
               MANIFEST.MF 
        FactoryContext.xml 

The short version of jar2's MANIFEST.MF is 
   Bundle-ClassPath: . 
   Bundle-Name: jar2 
   Bundle-SymbolicName: jar2 
   Bundle-Version: 1.0.0 
   Export-Package: com.abc 
   Import-Package: xyz 
   Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

Jar1 call a method of Jar2, that method is using bellow statement

> context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("FactoryContext.xml");

whenever it goes to this statement, it always throws exception say that FactoryContext.xml doesn not exist.  (i guest this file is not in classpath)

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Retagged with broader "osgi" tag, this isn't specific to Karaf/ServiceMix and you may get some more views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also posted my question on ServiceMix forum and i have got the answer from Freeman-2.
Here is the answer

```
You can try to put  FactoryContext.xml in a unique folder like META- 
INF/MyFactoryContext/FactoryContext.xml, then jar2 also export package   
META-INF.MyFactoryContext, and jar1 import package META- 
INF.MyFactoryContext, and  then should be able to use code like 
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/ 
MyFactoryContext/FactoryContext.xml"); 
in jar1.
```

Here is the link
http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/question-about-jar-bundle-and-classpath-td5602052.html